# redirect_uri in the authentication process for nightbot

Tags: python

I'm writing a small python script to connect with nightbot via the API. However, I'm stuck at the redirect_uri for the authentication step to get the authentication code required for the token. As I understand it, I need to setup some kind of server that can handle this authentication and then returns a token with which my script then can start using the API.
Is there any way I can do this without creating a server that will probably be used less than 10 times?
This script is only intended for my personal use and a handful other people, so although it is not good practice and I don't really like it (and tbh I don't fully understand what someone with malicious intent could do with it), I would consider having the client_secret of my app in code for simplicity if that solves my problem.

My code currently looks like this.

```
params = {
    'client_id': '{0}'.format(client_id),
    'redirect_uri': '{0}'.format(''),
    'response_type': 'token',
    'scope': '{0}'.format('channel_send commands'),
    'stat': '{0}'.format('test')
}
webbrowser.open('https://api.nightbot.tv/oauth2/authorize' + '?' + urllib.parse.urlencode(params))
```

When running this, the authorization side of nightbot redirects me to the normal login with the pop-up 'Missing required OAuth2 parameter(s)'.

Comment: One possible approach is to use the "implicit grant" flow, which eliminates the need for the redirect URI and the server-side code.

Comment: @AsiriHewage but with that I still need the redirect_uri, at least according to https://api-docs.nightbot.tv/#implicit-flow. What should I set it to?